# python parse string for patterned string

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, dataframe, delimiter

I need to parse through a Pandas DataFrame column containing a long string where I need to find an ID following a specific pattern of PXXXXX. The id is always starts 'P' and followed by 5 random character or number, ie PXYZAB.

For example,

```
   columnName
   |||||||||||||||||||||Fefelajfeaflekj;alfkjeaf_PXXXXX
   ||||XYz<,,,ffeals89fes|PXXXXX_fewalfeslfesfsfjfes
   wh;lajkfeklaflkejasefj;lase|||||xxxx_PXXXX|wha;felkjasf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  import pandas as pd

  df = read_excel(c:\\......)
  df.head()
```

Output

```
  String
  |||||fe;jlkajf;lkeja;fji_PXXXX
  ;ljf;oeiaf;ifs[op[[pof[PXXXX,;lkjf;lej;afle
  [xyzPXXXX]
```

solution

```
  df['patterns'] = df['String'].str.findall('P[A-Za-z0-9]{5}')
```

Output

```
  String                                           patterns  
  |||||fe;jlkajf;lkeja;fji_PXXXX                   PXXXXX
  ;ljf;oeiaf;ifs[op[[pof[PXXXX,;lkjf;lej;afle      PXXXXX
  [xyzPXXXX]                                       PXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

See if the below works for you..
*UPDATED with digit request*

```
import re
```

`s='||||XYz<,,,ffeals89fes|PUVWXY_fewalfeslfesfsfjfes\nwh;lajkfeklaflkejasefj;lase|||||xxxx_PA1CDE|wha;felkjasf'`

```
colIdx='Col Header Name in Data Frame where the string is' #OR just the 1 if it is 2nd column that you want to check and there are no headers in your data frame.
ids=[m for idx, row in df.iterrows()  for m in re.findall('P[A-Z0-9]{5}',row[colIdx])]:
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
PUVWXY
PA1CDE
```

Note that this only captures `P` followed five **capital** letters or digits.

Comment: How would I modify this code to incorporate to allow for Captial letters and numbers?

Comment: Would it be too much to ask how to format the s variable so that its a column in a DataFrame and have it loop through the rows?

Comment: am not sure of your DataFrame setup, but you get the idea. This will get all the ids that have been matched in the whole column.

Comment: im still trying to figure out what the ids for loop is trying to do , namely what the value of colIdx in row[colIdx]

Comment: `colIdx` is your dataframe column header. which would return that column's value from the row

Comment: Tell me how to you access from your dataframe the string to be checked from 9th row? With the help of that I can re-write the line so that it is more helpful for you

Comment: I actually found this solution:    df['String'].str.findall('P[A-Za-z0-9]{5}')   Thanks for the help and guiding me closer to a solution.

Comment: @HaroldChaw may be you can add it as an answer?